# Spring Data JPA - findBy mapped object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my legacy application, I have a country table, state table and a mapping table for country and state with few additional columns.

I have created an entity class like this.

```
class CountryStateMapping {

  @Id
  private long id;

  private Long countryId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
  private State state;

  //getters seters

}
```

My repository.

```
public interface CountryStateMapping extends JpaRepository<CountryStateMapping, Long>{
   Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByStateId(long stateId);
   Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByState(State state);
}
```

I would like to check if the state exists in the mapping table. Both of the below approaches do not work.

```
countryStateMapping.findByStateId(long stateId)
countryStateMapping.findByState(State state)
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Its not the correct way i feel.The correct way for doing this will be

```
    public interface CountryStateMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryStateMapping, Long>  {
               Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByStateId(long stateId);
               @Query("select s.something from State s" )
               Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByState(State state);
            }
```

This implies two things

1. By extending JpaRepository we get a bunch of generic CRUD methods to create, update, delete, and find

2.It allows Spring to scan the classpath for this interface and create a Spring bean for it.

Also you need some configuration.For that you need to create a configuration class to be used with your data source.You can find many examples to do the same and one such is  https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa.

You can also use custom queries and simple queries using the @Query  annotation.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I already extend the jparepository. My mistake. I corrected now.

Comment: then you need to add the configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an underscore for id like below;

```
public interface CountryStateMapping<CountryStateMapping, Long>{
   Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByState_Id(long stateId);
   Optional<CountryStateMapping> findByState(State state);
}
```